# Bash: Execute different functions based on date

Tags: bash, date, scripting

I'm trying to make a bash script which, when executed, runs a different set of commands based on whether the date is within a certain range. I only care to check the day and the month.

For example: Let's say I want a script which tells me the season based on the European calendar. I'd give it 4 paragraphs of code in the following format:

```
if date is between 01-03 and 01-06 then
    echo "It is spring"
if date is between 01-06 and 01-09 then
    echo "It is summer"
if date is between 01-09 and 01-12 then
    echo "It is autumn"
if date is between 01-12 and 01-03 then
    echo "It is winter"
```

This is certainly achievable using the `date` command. I'm just not sure how to use the month and day numbers in an efficient formula to check such ranges.

Comment: The day seems unnecessary (ignoring the overlap for June 1, Sept 1, Dec 1, and March 1); e.g., spring seems to be any day in month 3, 4, or 5.

Comment: Why not combine the month and day into a single number and compare those? You'll need to do something a little special with December, but it's straight forward. But @chepner is right since a season does not start mid-month.

Answer (score 2):

Use a case statement to match against a single string consisting of the month and date in a fixed format.

```
case $(date +%m-%d) in
  03-2[2-9]|03-3*|0[4-6]-[01]*|06-2[012]) echo "spring" ;;
  06-2[2-9]|06-3*|0[7-9]-[01]*|09-2[012]) echo "summer" ;;
  09-2[2-9]|09-3*|1[012]-[01]*|12-2[012]) echo "autumn" ;;
  12-2[2-9]|12-3*|0[1-3]-[01]*|03-2[012]) echo "winter" ;;
esac
```

Comment: That was just an example: In my use case I need the day as well.

Comment: Examples that don't match your use case aren't helpful.

Comment: i like it, but: Southern hemisphere?

Answer (score 1):

`date +%m` specifies a format that will have `date` only ouput the month number, so you can use that in your conditions :

```
current_month=$(date +%m)
if [[ $current_month > 2 && $current_month < 6 ]]; then
    echo "It is spring"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that for what I need, I can simply estimate whether it's the first or second half of the month. I managed to create a working script using this check:

```
current_month=$(date +%m)
current_day=$(date +%d)

if (( current_month == 1 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # January, first half
    echo "January, first half"
elif (( current_month == 1 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # January, second half
    echo "January, second half"
elif (( current_month == 2 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # February, first half
    echo "February, first half"
elif (( current_month == 2 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # February, second half
    echo "February, second half"
elif (( current_month == 3 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # March, first half
    echo "March, first half"
elif (( current_month == 3 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # March, second half
    echo "March, second half"
elif (( current_month == 4 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # April, first half
    echo "April, first half"
elif (( current_month == 4 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # April, second half
    echo "April, second half"
elif (( current_month == 5 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # May, first half
    echo "May, first half"
elif (( current_month == 5 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # May, second half
    echo "May, second half"
elif (( current_month == 6 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # June, first half
    echo "June, first half"
elif (( current_month == 6 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # June, second half
    echo "June, second half"
elif (( current_month == 7 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # July, first half
    echo "July, first half"
elif (( current_month == 7 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # July, second half
    echo "July, second half"
elif (( current_month == 8 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # August, first half
    echo "August, first half"
elif (( current_month == 8 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # August, second half
    echo "August, second half"
elif (( current_month == 9 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # September, first half
    echo "September, first half"
elif (( current_month == 9 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # September, second half
    echo "September, second half"
elif (( current_month == 10 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # October, first half
    echo "October, first half"
elif (( current_month == 10 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # October, second half
    echo "October, second half"
elif (( current_month == 11 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # November, first half
    echo "November, first half"
elif (( current_month == 11 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # November, second half
    echo "November, second half"
elif (( current_month == 12 )) && (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    # December, first half
    echo "December, first half"
elif (( current_month == 12 )) && (( current_day >= 16 ))
then
    # December, second half
    echo "December, second half"
else
    # Error
    echo "Error: Invalid date"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler version of the answer you posted:

```
read -r current_month current_day <<< $(date '+%B %d')

if (( current_day < 16 ))
then
    half=first
else
    half=second
fi

echo "$current_month, $half half"
```

Today's output:

```
June, first half
```

The `%B` format code provides the local's current full month name. Using `read` to get both values at the same time avoids the rare problem of getting dates of different months at exactly midnight on the last day of the month.

This script removes a [lot of repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by using that format string and building piece wise the string to be output.

Ten lines versus your 103.

Comment: Like I said, I need my script to execute different code based on each combination. The version I posted works fine for me none the less.

Comment: @MirceaKitsune: We can only answer questions using the information given. When a question asker gives partial information, asks about something other than what they really need help with and/or moves the target, it makes it next to impossible. The techniques I demonstrate in my answer considerably improve DRY and can be used more generally than just echoing a string.